# Replace rn with newline only where newline should be

Tags: php

I am currently recieving text that has `rn` where the newline - `\r\n` - should have been (most likely a result of compression).

In php, I would like to safely replace this with a `<br/>`.

Currently, what I have is

```
str_replace("rn", "<br/>", text);
```

But this would fail if somewhere where to input a word like `"corn"`.

Any way to make this work? I would expect it uses `preg_replace()` but not sure.

EDIT: An example of text would be `foo barrnbaz bop`

Comment: Most likely the result of `stripslashes()`.

Comment: What about: "I stood in the corner where my friends and cornerased what was written." On which grounds will `rn` be replaced?

Comment: @trincot That is the problem, there seems to be no good way to figure that out :/

Answer (score 0):

[`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) is the way to go here. You can use word boundaries `\b` so it doesn't match `rn` when it is a part of a word, e.g.

```
$text = preg_replace("/\brn\b/", "<br />", $text);
```

Comment: That would work, just that the text sometimes gets jumbled together, take a look at OP for an example.

Comment: @TheOnlyOneAround I don't really understand what you mean? `\b` prevents matches like `corn` or `rnxy`.

Comment: But the point is that sometimes text comes in like `foo barrnbaz bop`, it won't match that.

Comment: @TheOnlyOneAround Then there is not really a way to detect that if you want to replace there. Because it would be really hard to detect that `rn` isn't part of the word here: `barrnbaz` but here it would be: `corn`.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I will just have to do the unsafe way then.

Comment: @TheOnlyOneAround I would look into the problem why the backslashes get striped out of your string, which might get you to your goal.

Comment: I would say that it is `stripslashes()`, as @AbraCadaver said

Comment: @TheOnlyOneAround That could be it. So you would have to look there in the first place that you don't remove the backslashes for `\n\r`